# source code for auto-capture of image when camera is launched in an android app

Tags: android, android-camera

I am new to android programming.
I built an app which launches the camera via an intent when a button is pressed. But my requirement is that  as soon as the camera is launched, it should capture the image autmatically after appropriately focusing it without clicking the camera shutter button and store the image in SD card.
it would a great help if i could get a source code.
thanks

my code is :-

```
unsuccess_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 

        { add_text.setText("Not Successful");

         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              startActivity(cameraIntent);  

        }



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the surface view to get the Image from the camera and Camera hardware API to control the camera. May [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html) will help you

In Addition to this you can change your code to take the picture in some timer event/launch of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimerTask or Thread to perform capturing event at some particular time period. I had developed same application.

Comment: Hi, I have the same requirment and getting little confusion. Can you plz help me ?